# How to prevent Excel from converting the contents of a field in a database table into dates automatically when downloaded as a csv

Tags: sql, excel, csv, date, amazon-athena

When running a select statement where one of the fields included is the Runway Id of a given runway at a given airport in a database containing data on airports and runways I am working on, because these Ids are of the form ##/##, when I have the results I want and save the resulting table to a csv, many of the records in that Runway Id column become dates. Excel just cannot help itself I guess. This has happened both when the queries were ran in MySQL Workbench, and now again in Amazon Athena.

Here is what the results of the query itself look like in Athena:
[image]

And here is what the results look like in Excel even when its not formatted as an xlx file yet:
[image]

Is there anything I can do to prevent this travesty from continuing?

Comment: Import the csv file into Excel using either the legacy wizard or Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365). At the time of import, designate that column as text. You can make the import re-usable so you don't have to repeat the steps each time.

Comment: You can parse the runway field in the query to two different fields (main_rw, sub_rw, for example).

Comment: @Guy parse it in Athena or in Excel?

Comment: The parsing into two separate field is part of the query in Athena.